# How to get .json objects by id in Angular 2?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, filter

I'm trying to get objects by id from a JSON file after selecting an item from my drop-down list. So far I have managed to retrieve all the objects from JSON but not by ID.

**Typescript**

```js
showInfo() {
    var selected = this.diadikasies.filter(x=> x.content);
    console.log (selected);
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div *ngIf="diadikasies && diadikasies.length > 0" class="form-group">
    <label for="diadikasies">
        <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list" aria-hidden="true"></i> Please Select: </label>
    <select #proc (change)="showInfo()">
        <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled selected>Επιλέξτε Διαδικασία</option>
        <option *ngFor="let diad of diadikasies" [value]="diad.id">{{ diad.title.rendered }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with `find()` method like below

**TS file**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  description;

  opts = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Test 1',
    description: 'This is Test 1 description'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Test 2',
    description: 'This is Test 2 description'
  }];

  showInfo(value) {
    let selectedOpt = this.opts.find(opt => opt.id == value);
    this.description = selectedOpt.description;
  }
}
```

**In the template file**

```
<div *ngIf="opts && opts.length > 0" class="form-group">
    <label for="opts">
        <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list" aria-hidden="true"></i> Please Select: </label>
    <select #proc (change)="showInfo(proc.value)">
        <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled selected>Επιλέξτε Διαδικασία</option>
        <option *ngFor="let diad of opts" [value]="diad.id">{{ diad.name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>{{ description }}</div>
```

You can find the working example from here [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-swobmd)

Comment: Thank you so much. It was very simple, indeed, even though I hadn't thought about find().

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngModel and ngModelChange together to get the selected value

```
<select #proc [(ngModel)]="selectedObj" (ngModelChange)="showInfo()">
```

and inside showInfo method,

```
 var selected = this.diadikasies.filter(x=> x.id == this.selectedObj.id);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `x.id === this.selectedObj.id` in `filter`?